# Intermediate Value Property and Null Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I was trying to prove this three result which are equivalent. Recall $f$ is said to have the Intermediate Value Property in $[a, b]$ if $\forall c,d \in [a, b], \ y \in (f(c), f(d)) \ \exists x \in (c, d) \ / \ f(x)=y $

**Statement 1**

**Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $f \geq 0$. Suppose that $f$ has the Intermediate Value Property. Suppose also that $f \in \mathcal R[a, b]$ and that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$. Then $f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in [a, b]$.**

**Statement 2**

**Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f^2$ has the Intermediate Value Property. Suppose also that $f^2 \in \mathcal R[a, b]$ and that $\int_a^b f^2(x)\,dx = 0$. Then $f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in [a, b]$.**

**Statement 3**

**Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f$ has the Intermediate Value Property. Suppose also that $f^2 \in \mathcal R[a, b]$ and that $\int_a^b f^2(x)\,dx = 0$. Then $f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in [a, b]$.**

$\boxed{1 \Rightarrow 2}$

Trivial, as $f^2$ satisfies every condition for Statement 1, so $f^2 = 0$ and then $f = 0$.

$\boxed{2 \Rightarrow 3}$

If $f$ has the Intermediate Value Property, so does $f^2$ (Not very hard to prove)

$\boxed{3 \Rightarrow 1}$

As $f$ is bounded because of being integrable, $\exists K \geq f(x); K\geq 0$. Also, as $f \in \mathcal R[a, b]$, $f^2 \in \mathcal R[a, b]$ holds. Then

$0 \leq f^2 \leq Kf \Rightarrow 0 = \int_a^b 0 dx \leq \int_a^b f^2(x) dx \leq K \int_a^b f(x) dx = 0 \Rightarrow \int_a^b f^2(x) dx = 0$, and Statement 3 holds

The three statement are generalizations of weaker results. If we assume continuity or having a primitive the result holds. I would like to have an "elementary" proof without Measure Theory or Lebesgue Integral.

Comment: Why do you expect these results to hold?

Comment: Because with further assumption (for example, if $f$ has a primitive), statement do hold. It also can be the case that the statement is false, in which case i would like a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The answer is completely revamped with an easier counter-example.

---

The statement is actually false.

Recall that a function satisfying the Intermediate Value Property is called a [Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function).

- Let $g : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be any Darboux function which is not identically zero and vanishes on any dyadic rationals in $[0, 1]$ (that is, $g(k/2^n) = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ and $0 \leq k \leq 2^n$.)

  For example, such a function can be found by imitating the construction of [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function).
- Let $\phi : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Since $\phi$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, it is a Darboux function.

Then the composition $f = g \circ \phi$ satisfies the following properties:

1. If $C$ is the Cantor set, then $\phi([0,1]\setminus C)$ only consists of dyadic rationals, and so, $f$ is identically zero outside of $C$.
2. Since $f$ is the composition of two Darboux functions, it is again a Darboux function.
3. Since $0 \leq f \leq \mathbf{1}_C$, where $\mathbf{1}_C$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) for $C$, and $\mathbf{1}_C$ is Riemann-integrable with $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}_C = 0$, it follows that $f$ is also Riemann integrable and $\int_{0}^{1} f = 0$.

Therefore $f$ provides a counter-example to Statement 1.